# typedef-ed ref-qualified function type differs in behavior between gcc and clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

When I try to compile the following code:

```
struct A {
    void foo() & {
    }
};

int main()
{
    using F = void() &; // or 'typedef void F() &;'
    [[maybe_unused]] F A::*pf = &A::foo;
}
```

with clang this compiles, but when compiled with gcc it produces an error.

```
test.cc:9:37: error: cannot convert ‘void (A::*)() &’ to ‘void (A::*)()’ in initialization
    9 |     [[maybe_unused]] F A::*pf = &A::foo;
```

Which behavior is correct?

Comment: fyi if you use `[[maybe_unused]] auto A::*pf = &A::foo;`  both clang and gcc deduce the same type - `void (A::*)() &` - live - https://godbolt.org/z/3EYT8M7jY

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90780